# Merge Two HDD in Ubuntu

Tags: partition

I have 2 HDD installed in my PC. One of them is empty (I just added it) and the other one contains everything else.

**Output from fdisk:**

```
root@*****:~# sudo fdisk -l  
Disk /dev/sda: 100 GiB, 107374182400 bytes, 209715200 sectors   
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes   
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes    
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes    
Disklabel type: dos   
Disk identifier: *****   

Device     Boot Start     End   Sectors  Size Id Type  
/dev/sda1  *     2048 209715166 209713119  100G 83 Linux


Disk /dev/sdb: 100 GiB, 107374182400 bytes, 209715200 sectors  
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes  
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes   
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes  
Disklabel type: dos  
Disk identifier: ******
```

So the system is on `/dev/sda`. How can i merge the old HDD with the new one so i get a 200GB `/dev/sda` partition?

Comment: Just out of curiosity... is this a physical system or VM?  I ask because 100GB drives are relatively ancient.

Comment: @RonJohn The size reported by `fdisk` is 100 x 2^30 bytes to the byte. That feels much more like a VM disk image than a physical drive, though of course it *could* still be a physical drive.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling but then, OP specifically writes "My **PC**", which sounds pretty "physical"...

Comment: @RonJohn Yeah, I know... it's odd, and hopefully we'll get clarification soon.

Answer (score 11):

Sorry, but there's no such thing as merging two HDDs.

What you *can* do is use LVM to create a volume group which contains both disks, and then create a logical volume that's ~200GB. Roughly-speaking, the steps boil down to the following:

1. Back up your `/dev/sda1`
2. Familiarize yourself with how your boot loader is currently configured (ex. GRUB2) and ensure there's a way for it to boot from LVM. For example, GRUB2 can boot from LVM, but you'll likely need a *GRUB partition* to do so.
3. Re-partition `/dev/sda` according to what you learned in step 2. For example, you may need a small partition for GRUB2 and the rest can be dedicated to LVM. You don't need to partition `/dev/sdb`.
4. Create two LVM physical volumes, one on each disk. For example, `pvcreate /dev/sda2 && pvcreate /dev/sdb`
5. Create a volume group which contains the two physical volumes. Ex: `vgcreate vg0 /dev/sda2 /dev/sdb`
6. Create a logical volume for your filesystem. Ex: `lvcreate -ay -l 100%FREE --name rootfs vg0`
7. Format your new filesystem. Ex: `mkfs.ext4 /dev/vg0/rootfs`
8. Restore your backup to `/dev/vg0/rootfs`
9. Mount `/dev/vg0/rootfs` and modify the `/etc/fstab` so that the "/" filesystem is mounted from `/dev/vg0/rootfs`.
10. You may have to reconfigure your boot loader so it knows where to find the Linux kernel in your LVM logical volume.

As you may have guessed, `/dev/vg0/rootfs` is *essentially* your two HDDs merged.

Comment: This needs a **BIG** caveat in that any kind of combining or striping across multiple storage devices typically means that if either storage device breaks, you lose all your data. I don't know about LVM specifically, but very few RAID 0 type systems handle that case gracefully, and many don't handle it at all.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling by it's very nature, RAID 0 (aka striping) can't handle it gracefully.

Comment: @RonJohn Depending on the implementation, partial data recovery may be possible after losing a portion of a RAID 0 array. If it's truly striped then data recovery is unlikely; but if it's a *concatenation* of devices, partial data recovery may very well be possible. Either way, it's something one should be aware of.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling, LVM uses concatenation.  If you want some other method of grouping drives (eg. RAID 0), it has to take place at a lower level.

Comment: `btrfs` can also be used to append two or more drives....and ext4 can be easily converted to btrfs (warning: backup first is very strongly recommended).